# git-tfs dealing with tags

Tags: git-tfs

I have a question regarding git-tfs integration and how it deals with labels.

While working with git-tfs, how do you deal with labels? Are they imported into git?

Are "tags" also "exported" when pushing changes back to tfs?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, changesets are not tagged or labelled when pushing changes back up to TFS.
When  pulling from TFS, git-tfs tags commits with "tfs/default/Cnnnn" tags to make it easy to track the TFS changesets you have pulled, but no other labels from TFS are used.

If you need this I'd suggest you request it as a feature on the [github project](https://github.com/git-tfs/git-tfs) site.

Answer (score 3):

The development I made to support tfs labels has been merge https://github.com/git-tfs/git-tfs/pull/256
That's now in the stable version for quite some time...

But there is no way with git-tfs to push a tag to Tfs :( because in tfs, a label is not just a tag like in git but a real changeset on its own and it is not easy to make it. I have not needed it, that's why I never developed this feature!

Use the "Source control Explorer" if you want to create a label...